# How to run a application locally on an out of date node version

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, nvm

I have an app that runs on node 12 and 14 via nvm.

```
% nvm current    
v14.21.3
```

but when i try and call ionic i get the error:

```
ERR: Your Node.js version is v14.21.3. Node.js 14 reached end-of-life on 2023-04-30 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.
```

Comment: use NVM it's best tool for changing node versions https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: can you uninstall and install the desired node version via nvm? I saw couple of answers claiming to solve that

Comment: Hi I’m using nvm to install the node versions and use them for the app, but always get the error with both node 12 and 14.

I was hoping there’s an override or something to tell node to run on an old version but can’t find one

Answer (score 0):

Use a node package Manager to downgrade/upgrade node versions.

Comment: ive done a nvm uninstall and reinstall of the both 12 and 14 is that what you mean?